# Problem with mounting NTFS USB HDD via Tuxera in Lion

Tags: macos, mount, ntfs

I've just updated to Lion and noticed that I cannot mount my NTFS USB HDD. I'm using Tuxera and it gives me the error listed below.

Has anybody encountered this error? Any working solution will be appreciated, thanks in regards.

```
Tuxera NTFS could not mount /dev/disk1s1
at /Volumes/MYHDD because the following problem occurred:

CBCIO activated with:
  cp.fildes=3
  cp.blockSize=524288
  cp.items=32
  cp.mode=1
  cp.flushInterval=1000
/Library/Filesystems/fusefs.fs/Support/fusefs.kext failed to load - (libkern/kext) link error; check the system/kernel logs for errors or try kextutil(8).
the MacFUSE file system is not available (71)
__ntfs_volume_release(): Inode 9 still have 1 references.
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had the same problem, and after a search over the web, I found the following updated package of macfuse that worked for me: http://www.tuxera.com/mac/macfuse-core-10.5-2.1.9.dmg

Answer (score 0):

This solution helped me without problem, since I couldn't finish last step, immediately after that could not mount stopped. I have Lion 10.7.5 Macbook Pro 2011 and have NTFS Mac-fuse solution installed from early beginning. Don't stop be interested in know, there are solutions for Paragon and some other to. This looks quite dificult for me at first look but now I finally tried it and it takes about 10 minutes. Just don't be scare if you don't know terminal yet, then you'll be prompted to type password it looks like you can't type but you can. Just type and press enter.

<strike>Here's the link http://fernandoff.posterous.com/ntfs-write-support-on-osx-lion-with-ntfs-3g-f (sometimes it takes little bit longer to load)</strike>

Hope it helps

PS: Sorry, I don't have time to read everything, just found working solution so I decided to post it everywhere